# como usar html no corpo de um select

Tags: html, query, oracle, select, apex

Em uma página do apex, eu tenho uma select e preciso que caso essa select retorne null, um simbolo em html seja apresentado.

Ex:

```
select PLC_ID, 
CONTA,
CONTAB,
CIA,
NOMECONTA,
RESPONSAVEL, 

CASE WHEN VCAREA is null THEN
                 '<span class="fa fa-check-circle is-open" style="color:green" title="Análise Realizado para essa conta" alt=""></span>'
ELSE null END as area,

EBTIDA, 
DATA_CRIACAO,
ATUALIZADO_POR,
DATA_ATUALIZACAO
from #OWNER#.Plano
```

Eu sei que essa query funciona, porém o apex não renderiza o HTML. Aparece em forma de texto:

[image: HTML Não renderizado]

Eu gostaria que aparecesse da seguinte maneira:

[image: HTML Renderizado]

Eu não sei o porquê disso estar acontecendo

Answer (score -1):

Isso é um comportamento padrão para evitar Cross Site Script (XSS), então o apex não executa HTMl, CSS ou JS a não ser que explicitamente informado que aquele report é seguro.

Mas é bem simples:

- Seleciona a coluna no Page Designer
- No lado direito onde tem as propriedades da coluna, procura por escape special characters
- Deve estar ligado/marcado, então desliga ele
- salva e executa. o html será renderizado como você precisa.

Esse problema é bem comum, eu causo ele umas 2 vezes por mÊs aqui no trabalho... rsrsrsrs..

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).